# Headphones problem with Ubuntu 18.04 - no sound on them when it is plugged in

Tags: 18.04, sound, headphones

here`s another problem with the **Dell Inspiron 3181 Chromebook**. It was very hard to find a way to make its speakers work. Now, I have a problem with headphones. When I plugged in - the **Volumecontrol** panel indicate -

> Headphones (plugged in)

but nothing happens. Built-in speakers continuing to play, but no one in the headphones - complete silence. Please help me with advice how to cure this problem. I have read a lot of articles in order to solve it - but no success yet. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Go to "Settings->Sound" and check what both front and rear output is enabled and volume not zero

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have no muted outputs:

[image: Before plug in headphones]
Before plug in headphones

[image: After plug in headphones]
After plug in headphones

**Edited:**
We have a BIG progress. I have decide to start `alsamixer` and guess what - as the mate above said - Headphones was 00, when I turn the ^ button the sound comes.

[image: And here we have sound]
And here we have sound

Horray !!!! Now I am trying to make work-only headphones when plugged in, instead work both - speakers and the headphones. Any help will be appreciated.